# How do I capture os.Stdout output into a string for testing purposes?

Tags: go, testing

I have a function which produces output to os.Stdout that I would like to unit test.  How can I capture the output into a string which I can compare in my unit tests?

```
  func f() {
       // How to capture "hello\n"?
      fmt.Fprintln(out, "hello")
  }
```

Comment: If you use the “log” package instead of “fmt” for writing your logs, that package contains the ability to customize the destination for logs. You can capture them in a byte buffer during tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Classical Test Case Approach**

Write your function to take an optional io.Writer which defaults to stdout, but lets you pass in an io.Writer.  This will give you the ability to capture all output into a bytes.Buffer which can be used in the test cases.

```
  // f writes to stdout, or to an io.Writer if passed in.
  func f(fd ...io.Writer) {
      var out io.Writer
      switch len(fd) {
      case 0:
          out = os.Stdout
      case 1:
          out = fd[0]
      default:
          panic("called with too many parms")
      }
      fmt.Fprintln(out, "hello")
  }
```

When you call the function with no parameter, you get your usual expected operation of writing to stdout.

```
      f()       // Writes to stdout
```

For testing, pass a bytes.Buffer. When the function returns, the buffer will contain the output written by the function, ready for testing.

```
      var b bytes.Buffer  // capture output in b
      f(&b)

      fmt.Printf("<%s>\n", b.String())
```

An additional benefit of this approach is that the function can now easily write to a destination other than stdout if desired.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/3Kn_ht3ylE-

Comment: an alternate way: set the signature to one single writer argument : `func f(w io.Writer) { ...`, allow `nil` value, and use `os.Stdout` in this case : `if w == nil { w = os.Stdout }`. Your solution definitely works, here are 2 remarks about it: it also allows to write `f(os.Stdout, os.Stderr, file)` without the compiler complaining (yet the 2 extra args are completely ignored), and may make for weirder changes if you need to add *other* arguments to your function.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [os.Pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Pipe), and restore it with the `os.Stdout`. One concern is that there's a potential race condition capturing/restoring `os.Stdout` in a concurrent situation, however, maybe it could be Ok for testing purposes.

```golang
func main() {
    storeStdout := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    // call f()
    // for example just print hello
    fmt.Println("hello")

    w.Close()
    out, _ := io.ReadAll(r)
    // restore the stdout
    os.Stdout = storeStdout

    fmt.Printf("Got result: %s", out)
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/F6EbTyYS3iw)

Related: Note that [log.SetOutput()](https://pkg.go.dev/log#Logger.SetOutput) can be used to capture logging output.

Comment: Based on my experience this is the better solution.